# Advice on my workout plan

Tags: running-training-plan

### hi im shayan and im a beginner in fitness , i wanted to get my body ready for MMA and i thought it would be good idea to get my body ready first so i asked a friend who's a gym coach in my neighborhood to give me a workout plan and he gave me this =

Day 1:

Squats: 3 sets of 8 reps

Push-Ups: 3 sets of 8 reps

Bent-Over Rows: 3 sets of 8 reps

Planks: 3 sets of 30-60 seconds

Rest 2 days

Day 2:

Deadlifts: 3 sets of 8 reps

Pull-Ups or Lat Pulldowns: 3 sets of 8 reps

Overhead Press: 3 sets of 8 reps

Russian Twists: 3 sets of 12 reps (each side)

---

he gave me this and told me that he will help me with them and before i wanted to start i wanted to know opinion of experienced people first.
im 178 cm in height and 90 in weight.